# OpenCV(java) Rubik's Cube recognition color correction

Tags: java, opencv

So I made this rubiks cube program that solves itself and is playable,
now I wanted to make a real time rubiks cube recognition addition so I can input a live cube into the program.

I have currently been able to write the code for the camera, and the shape recognition by color.
My problem is that since the lighting is always changing and glare, I can never get the right HSV scalar for each colored face, I added in a feature to manually set each face's has values but that is very unreliable and tedious.

My two questions are:
1) how can I correct the image colors so that I will be able to get good results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically reduced the RGB color scale fromaround 16 million colors to 512 colors which made recognition a lot easier.